# Pyspark: UDF to apply regex to each line in dataframe

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I want to check each line in my dataframe for any funky characters that might be messing up my schema when saving out the file.

I read in my files:

```
a = spark.read.csv(
    "s3a://mybucket/ML_teradata_feeds/PTEF/AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_FACT_01_TO_10_202009.dat-1.gz").unionAll(spark.read.csv(
    "s3a://mybucket/ML_teradata_feeds/PTEF/AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_FACT_01_TO_10_202009.dat-2.gz")).unionAll(spark.read.csv(
    "s3a://mybucket/ML_teradata_feeds/PTEF/AM_PROGRAM_TUNING_EVENT_FACT_01_TO_10_202009.dat-3.gz"))
```

Then make a UDF from a regex, and run each line through the udf to see if the line conforms to the regex:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

regex = re.compile('[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9\-\/]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|.*\|.*\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}')

def isInteresting( line ):
    if len(regex.match(line).group(0)) is not None: 
        return True
    else:
        return False

isInterestingUdf = f.udf(isInteresting)
interestingLines = a.withColumn( 'isInteresting', isInterestingUdf('_c0') )
```

But this is just printing out every line, instead of filtering out the lines that get caught by the regex. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to fix your `isInteresting` func. It will throw an Exception if not matched. After adding `isInteresting` Column to your a DataFrame, you need to apply filter statement `isInteresting=True`

```
regex = re.compile('[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9\-\/]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|.*\|.*\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}')

def isInteresting( line ):
    if regex.match(line):
        if len(regex.match(line).group(0)): 
            return True
    return False
isInterestingUdf = f.udf(isInteresting)
interestingLines = a.withColumn( 'isInteresting', isInterestingUdf('_c0') )
#filter only interestingLines
interestingLines = interestingLines.filter('isInteresting=True')
```

EDIT:
What I suggest is using `rlike` function instead of udf (it is far more performant)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
a.filter(f.col('_c0').rlike('[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9]{0,19}\|[0-9\-\/]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9]{0,10}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|.*\|.*\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}\|[0-9\s\-:\.]{0,26}'))
```

Comment: Agree with that the use of `rlike` is better not only for  maintainability, but mostly for performance!